# Hazelcast reactive support for WriteThrough in Hazelcast 4.2

Tags: postgresql, hazelcast, reactive

We wanted to implement  WriteThrough/write behind in Hazelcast using MapStore for Postgres DataStore using ReactiveClient. But could not succeed and we are also not getting any sample for reactive approach.
We are implementing MapStore Interface to achieve  WriteThrough Caching Pattern.
we have to inject the Respository in Mapstore and we are trying inject using @Autowired Annotation.

But we are not able to do, we are getting error  repository as null.

Can we get some working example for Hazelcast 4.2 with Postgress as Datastore in reactive way?
Thanks
Jeni Ambrose

We tried with Autowiring the Repositories in Mapstore implementation

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
    @Bean
    public Config config(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        Config config = new ClasspathYamlConfig("hazelcast.yml");

        MapStoreConfig accountMapStoreConfig = new MapStoreConfig();
        accountMapStoreConfig.setInitialLoadMode(MapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode.EAGER);
        accountMapStoreConfig.setEnabled(true);
        accountMapStoreConfig.setImplementation(new AccountMapLoader(accountRepository));
       
        MapConfig accountMapConfig = new MapConfig();
        accountMapConfig.setName("account");
        accountMapConfig.setMapStoreConfig(accountMapStoreConfig);
        
        config.getMapConfigs().put(accountMapConfig.getName(), accountMapConfig);
 
        return config;
    }
```

You can have most (or none!) of the config in a static file, load it, and amend it to add Spring managed bits.

Also, 4.2 is old, use 5.2.1 or whatever is newest when you get to doing this.

Comment: HI.. Thank you @Neil Stevenson. Do we have Reactive Hazelcast Client as we have in reddis. Can you please provide us Github Link or working Code as we are new to Hazelcast.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific example, sorry. If you check out operations such as `iMap.putAsync(K,V)` that might get you started.